# Using Apache Kafka as an alternative to FTP

Tags: apache-kafka, ftp

I'm new to the open-source technology.
I just want to know whether we can use Apache Kafka as an alternative to our regular FTP where we keep files at a certain location from where the end user accesses them.
The source for my files will mainly be SAP HANA. From where I want to push files into Kafka, from where the end user will be able to consume it.
Can someone suggest from where to start or list down the steps in achieving this ?

Comment: wouldn't even try it, kafka is not an alternative to a ftp server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka is not a 1:1 replacement, no.

Can you use Apache Kafka for streaming data integration between systems, in a more scalable and less brittle way than FTP? Sure. Can you just switch one out for the other? No.

Have a look at these resources to understand more about what Kafka can be used for and how to use it:

- http://go.rmoff.net/devoxx18-embrace-the-anarchy
- http://go.rmoff.net/devoxx18-build-streaming-pipeline
- http://rmoff.dev/ksny19-no-more-silos

Answer (score 1):

Kafka is typically not meant for large data such as files. I suppose that you would want to do some operations on those files. The way you can do is to pass the references to those files to a Kafka topic and let your consumers read the data from those files using those references.

I don't know about SAP Hana. But you may be interested in 
[SAP Hana Connector for Kafka](https://www.confluent.io/connector/sap-hana-connector/)